# Syntax error keeps saying, perhaps you forgot a comma

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
sentence = "I think it's interesting that 'cologne' rhymes with 'alone'"

words = break_words(sentence)
sorted_words = sort_sentence(sentence)

print("\\", "{}" has {} words.format(sentence, count_words(words))) #THIS IS THE LINE
print("The words are:", words)
print("The sorted words are:", sort_words)

print_first_word(words)
print_last_word(words)
print_first_and_last_word(sentence)
```

Comment: Did you mean to type: `print("\\", "{} has {} words".format(sentence, count_words(words)))`?

Answer (score 1):

Everything preceding `.format` should be a string. Try this:

```
print("{} has {} words".format(sentence, count_words(words)))
```

Comment: This rule explains the syntax-error, but the solution is probably not what was intended to demarcate the original sentence from the rest of the printed output. What if OP wants the sentence to be in (double-)quotes ?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [Christian Dean's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72923658/syntax-error-keeps-saying-perhaps-you-forgot-a-comma/72924040#comment128801110_72923658), the part `has {} words` is outside the quoted string.

But here you are probably trying to quote a word inside the string, so you should escape the inner double-quotes by a backslash (`\`):

```
print("\"{}\" has {} words".format(sentence, count_words(words)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your print statement with the one mentioned below and it should work:

```
print("\\", "{} has {} words".format(sentence, count_words(words))) #THIS IS THE LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

To put something into quotes inside a string-literal you have a few options:

1. put it into different quotes than the string itself, here single-quotes

   ```py
   print("'{}' has {} words".format(sentence, count_words(words)))  # single quoted
   ```

   > 'I think it's interesting that 'cologne' rhymes with 'alone'' has 9 words
2. put it into quotes outside of the string itself

   ```py
   print("{} has {} words".format('"' + sentence + '"', count_words(words)))  # quoted outside
   ```

   > "I think it's interesting that 'cologne' rhymes with 'alone'" has 9 words
3. put it into escaped double-quotes ([escape](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/lexical_analysis.html#escape-sequences) by prefixed backslash)

   ```py
   print("\"{}\" has {} words".format(sentence, count_words(words)))  # escaped double-quotes
   ```

   > "I think it's interesting that 'cologne' rhymes with 'alone'" has 9 words

Since your original sentence has single-quotes inside, I would prefer option 2 or 3 with double-quotes wrapped around the sentence.